# patten search in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I am trying to search a string 'Test^' in another string 'test1 Test2 Test^ test'. I find that

```
re.search(r'\bTest\^\B', 'test1 Test2 Test^ test')
```

would work but

```
re.search(r'\bTest\^\b', 'test1 Test2 Test^ test')
```

would not work. I am a bit confused as I think I should use \b for the word boundary of 'Test^' (both sides have an empty space. Is it because Python treats the end of the string as '^' so it is a non word boundary?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`\b` means transition from "word character" to "non-word character" or vice versa. Word characters are alphanumeric characters, plus underscore, `_`. `^` is not a word character, nor is   (space), so the transition from one to another is not a word boundary; as observed, it matches `\B`, not `\b`. If you want a space specific check, you'd need to explicitly use look-ahead `(?=)` or look-behind `(?<=)` assertions (possibly negated, depending on use case) with `\s`/`\S`.

Comment: Thanks. That explains. As I still want to use a non word boundary, I use r'\bTest\^(?=\W)' and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the caret is considered a word boundary, i.e. delimiter. The one with the capital "\B" is ignored and so isn't looking for a word boundary. The caret is a non-word character.

So, it should not be part of a regex pattern that's looking for words only.

https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html